# Connect to Oracle 10g through Internet using Pool

Tags: asp.net, oracle, dotconnect

Our .Net webservice provides data for about 1000 users and 3000 request per seconds.
If it connects to a database reside on LAN, every thing is OK. But when it connects to a database through The Internet, and naturally, connection will some times not stable and it lead to dead connections. In client's connection pool, connections are still there and on the server also but they are dead already. No connection will be created after that because of full connection pool.
If that happend, we have to reset IIS :( and it happens a lot.
We are using free version of DotConnect 7.3.132.0, Oracle 10g and webservice written in .Net 2.0.
Please help :(

Comment: Does dead client detection help here?

Comment: I do not understand your question. I try to ClearPool but no luck :(

Comment: speak to your dba and check the Dead Client Detection settings in the sqlnet.ora on the rdbms server host. I am not sure, it could help.

Comment: DB is ok with dead connections, problems are on client side.

Answer (score 0):

We move our webservice to the same LAN of DB. Every thing is fine.